# Cannot migration from old 3.4.2 keycloak to latest version

Tags: migration, keycloak

I'm in charge of the migration of an old keycloak ( 3.4.2 ) to the latest version. I already migrated the database and the template. 
The last thing that poses problem is custom providers for Account and Login.
I have two custom providers that extends :

- FreeMarkerAccountProviderFactory
- FreeMarkerLoginProviderFactory

At first, no providers was loaded at the starting of keycloak in version > 4.x. I investigate, and i found that override the default `getId()` method to return a value other than the default "freemarker" makes keycloak load them again.

But after that if i try to access the login page, i got a nullpointer exception on `org.keycloak.services.resources.account.AccountFormService.init(AccountFormService.java:139)`

Any idea ?

Edit : spi in provider are declared in META-INF/services and provider in standalone.xml

Edit 2 : I share the loginFormProvider as it as the same problem, trigger the same error but it less complicated in it's implementation

```
public class KeycloakFreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider extends FreeMarkerLoginFormProvider {
    public KeycloakFreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider(KeycloakSession session, FreeMarkerUtil freeMarker) {
        super(sesssion, freeMarker);
    }

    public Response createResponse(LoginFormsPages page) {
        List<Foo> foo = // loading foo entities
        List<Bar> bar = // loading bar entities

        super.attributes.put("foo", foo);
        super.attributes.put("bar", bar);
        return super.createResponse(page);
    }
}

public class KeycloakFreeMarkerLoginProviderFactory extends FreeMarkerLoginFormsProviderFactory {

    private FreeMarkerUtil freeMarker;

    public KeycloakFreeMarkerLoginProviderFactory() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public LoginFormsProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
        return new KeycloakFreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider(session, this.freeMarker);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope config) {
        this.freeMarker = new FreeMarkerUtil();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        this.freeMarker = null;
    }

    /* Without getId() or with a value at freeMarker, the provider
    is not load. With other value, get NPE */
    @Override
    public String getId() {
         return "custom.provider";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does Keycloak start up if you omit your two providers?

Comment: Yeah. It start. Provider are well declared and works in 3.4.2

Comment: What about the login page?  Does it work without the NPE if you omit the two providers?  Just trying to narrow down the cause of the problem...

Comment: Yeah it works. My custom theme is displayed. Only data that providers must load are not present

Comment: Ok, great.  So this tells us that the database was migrated correctly, and the problem is something to do with the providers.  In the source code on `AccountFormService` line 139, Keycloak is attempting to get a provider of type `AccountProvider`.  So I'd suspect there is something wrong there.  Can you update your question to share your code for your `FreeMarkerAccountProviderFactory` and the corresponding provider implementation?

Comment: For the record, line 139 is `account = session.getProvider(AccountProvider.class).setRealm(realm).setUriInfo(session.getContext().getUri()).setHttpHeaders(headers);`

Comment: I added the code example

Comment: Thanks for adding the code.  My best guess is that one of the chain of calls in line 139 is returning null.  You might try attaching a debugger and seeing what each of those return.  Could be that the provider is not getting picked up correctly (though your config looks ok).  If it is getting picked up, I'd check what it returns for setRealm, setUriInfo, and setHttpHeaders.  These might be in the parent class that you extend.

Comment: I already debugged the code. it's session.getProvider(AccountProvider.class) that return NPE. But i was unable to find why the Hashmap that contains all loaded providers does not contain those too.

Comment: Ah ok, we're getting warmer now.  I'll post an answer that might help since it gives me more room, formatting, etc.  Not sure if it's actually going to solve your problem but hopefully it will

Comment: @Scandinave i'm trying to do this migration. What steps did you take?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments chain, it appears that the problem is that the provider is not getting picked up by Keycloak.  You have a couple of options for bundling a custom provider with Keycloak: as a module, or as a deployed war/ear/jar in the deployments directory.

Here's how to do it as a module:

You'll need to add some configuration (`module.xml`), and your jar, to the modules directory structure.  It should look like something like this:

```
(keycloak root)
|- modules
   |- system
      |- layers
         |- keycloak
            |- com
               |- yourcompany
                  |- yourmodule
                     |- main
                        |- your-module-name.jar
                        |- module.xml (see below)
```

Your `module.xml` should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module name="com.yourcompany.yourmodule" xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.6">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="your-module-name.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- whatever module dependencies you need go here -->
        <!-- these are just an example; you may or may not need them -->
        <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
        <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-core"/>
        <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services"/>
        <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi"/>
        <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Additionally, you'll need to configure `standalone.xml` and/or possibly `standalone-ha.xml` depending on your scenario (The default Keycloak Docker image uses `-ha.xml` by default).  The pertinent section should look something like this:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-server:1.1">
        <web-context>auth</web-context>
        <providers>
            <provider>
                classpath:${jboss.home.dir}/providers/*
            </provider>
<!-- add this -->
            <provider>
                module:com.yourcompany.yourmodule
            </provider>
<!-- end add -->
        </providers>
        <master-realm-name>master</master-realm-name>
        <scheduled-task-interval>900</scheduled-task-interval>
        ...
    </subsystem>
```

Lastly, like you mention, you'll need the correct config in your META-INF/services directory: a file with the fully qualified classname of the ProviderFactory as defined by the SPI, with one line containing the fully qualified classname of your implementation.  In your case, the file should be called `org.keycloak.forms.login.LoginFormsProviderFactory` and its value should be one line: `(com.yourpackage).KeycloakFreeMarkerLoginProviderFactory`

If it's picked up, you should be able to see it listed in the providers config in the admin UI.  To view, log in to the admin console, click on your username in the upper right, and select "Server Info", then click on the "Providers" tab.  You should see your provider listed under "login".

Comment: I will check tomorrow at work if there is no error on my side but I doubt. This is the process I have follow to make it work in 3.4.2. But let see.

Comment: I have checked all the config again, and all is well configured. I really don't know what is missing.

Comment: @Mark : the provider tag for module is added when the provider is added with the command line (jboss CLI with instruction '/subsystem=keycloak-server:list-add'). This must not be present in the standalone.xml file, suppress them before running the migration script. Instead, simply copy the .jar of your providers in the deployment directory before.